Find Duplicate Subscription for overlapping period
I need to identify valid subscription for users for different order placed.
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE customer_orders(
    customer_id VARCHAR
  , product_id VARCHAR
  , subscription_start_date DATE
  , subscription_end_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO customer_orders
VALUES
  ('customer_id_001', 'product_id_001', '2024-01-01', '2024-01-31'),
  ('customer_id_001', 'product_id_001', '2024-02-01', '2024-02-29'),
  ('customer_id_001', 'product_id_001', '2024-03-01', '2024-03-31'),
  ('customer_id_001', 'product_id_001', '2024-04-01', '2024-04-15'),
  ('customer_id_001', 'product_id_001', '2024-04-01', '2024-04-30');

SELECT * FROM customer_orders ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5;

In this data, we have an invalid order order_id_004 as there is a subsequent order order_id_005, which covers the subscription of whole month. I need to flag this record for audit purpose.
CUSTOMER_ID    PRODUCT_ID  SUBSCRIPTION_START_DATE SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE COMMENTS 
customer_id_001     product_id_001  2024-01-01  2024-01-31 VALID ORDER
customer_id_001     product_id_001  2024-02-01  2024-02-29 VALID ORDER
customer_id_001     product_id_001  2024-03-01  2024-03-31 VALID ORDER
customer_id_001     product_id_001  2024-04-01  2024-04-15 INVALID ORDER
customer_id_001     product_id_001  2024-04-01  2024-04-30 VALID ORDER

Here is work in progress, producing invalid results:
SELECT   
    c1.customer_id 
  , c1.product_id 
  , c1.subscription_start_date 
  , c1.subscription_end_date  
  , CASE WHEN c1.subscription_start_date BETWEEN c2.subscription_start_date AND c2.subscription_end_date
           OR c1.subscription_end_date   BETWEEN c2.subscription_start_date AND c2.subscription_end_date
           OR c2.subscription_start_date BETWEEN c1.subscription_start_date AND c1.subscription_end_date
         THEN 'Duplicate Subscription'
         ELSE 'Valid Subscription'
    END AS comment     
FROM customer_orders c1
INNER JOIN customer_orders c2 
   ON c1.customer_id = c2.customer_id
  AND c1.product_id  = c2.product_id
GROUP BY ALL  
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5;


Try something like this:
WITH src AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY customer_id, product_id, subscription_start_date, subscription_end_date) AS RN
      FROM customer_orders
)
SELECT   
    c1.customer_id 
  , c1.product_id 
  , c1.subscription_start_date 
  , c1.subscription_end_date  
  , IFF(c2.customer_id IS NOT NULL, 'Duplicate Subscription', 'Valid Subscription') AS comment
  , IFF(DATEDIFF(DAY, c2.subscription_start_date, c2.subscription_end_date) >= DATEDIFF(DAY, c1.subscription_start_date, c1.subscription_end_date), 'INVALID ORDER', 'VALID ORDER') AS Status
FROM src c1
LEFT JOIN src c2 
   ON c1.customer_id = c2.customer_id
  AND c1.product_id  = c2.product_id
  AND c1.RN <> c2.RN
  AND c1.subscription_start_date <= c2.subscription_end_date
  AND c2.subscription_start_date <= c1.subscription_end_date  
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4;


Thannks @Michael Golos

Thanks Michael for the quick response but I don't have CUSTOMER_ORDER_ID in my source (file) anymore so had to update the description.

You should have some kind of identifier that uniquely identifies such orders. If you don't have it then it can be generated manually using, for example, the ROW_NUMBER function, see the modified answer.
